# Having trouble executing my custom program transaction on devnet/testnet

Tags: react

I've followed along with other peoples examples but I keep getting the 0x65 custom program error. I'm using @solana/web3.js, @solana/wallet-adapter-react, @solana/buffer-layout, and js-sha256

```
const buyTickets = async (programId: PublicKey, user: PublicKey, amount: number, referral: PublicKey) => {
try {
  const [dashboardAccount] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([Buffer.from('dashboard')], programId);
  const dashboardAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(dashboardAccount);
  const dashboardResponse = DashboardResponse.decode(dashboardAccountInfo!.data);
  setDashboardInfo(dashboardResponse);

  const [userdataAccount] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from('dashboard'), publicKey!.toBuffer()],
    programId
  );

  const transaction = new Transaction({ feePayer: publicKey! });
  const functionName = 'initializeUserdata';
  const stuff = Buffer.from(
      sha256.sha256
        .create()
        .update('soltrain:' + functionName)
        .arrayBuffer()
    ).slice(0,8);
  const userdataInitializationInstruction = new TransactionInstruction({
    keys: [
      {
        pubkey: userdataAccount,
        isWritable: true,
        isSigner: false,
      },
      {
        pubkey: publicKey!,
        isWritable: true,
        isSigner: true,
      },
      {
        pubkey: SystemProgram.programId,
        isWritable: false,
        isSigner: false,
      },
    ],
    data: stuff,
    programId: programId,
  });
  transaction.add(userdataInitializationInstruction);
  const blockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
  transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash.blockhash;
  console.log(transaction);
  const signedTransaction = await signTransaction!(transaction);

  // Send the signed transaction
  await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction.serialize());
  // signTransaction(transaction);
  // sendTransaction(transaction, connection).then((txid) => {
  //   console.log(`Transaction submitted: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txid}?cluster=devnet`);
  // });
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error fetching account data:', error);
}
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0x65 means thats there is no fallback function. This means thats your function identifier is wrong. So its searching for a fallback, but there is none defined in the program.
I think in your case it should be

```
global:initializeUserdata
```

or

```
global:initialize_userdata
```

depending on how the function is named in your program.

You can find the anchor descriminator implementation here:
https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/lang/attribute/account/src/lib.rs#L93-L107

Since you are using anchor the easier way would be to use the anchor client. This would look something like this:

```
  import { yourProgram } from "../target/types/yourType";


  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);

  const program = anchor.workspace.yourProgram as Program<YourProgram>;
  const wallet = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;
  const connection = provider.connection;
  const transaction = await program.methods
    .initializeUserdata()
    .accounts({
      someAccounts
    })
    .transaction()

   const txSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
provider.connection,
  transaction,
  [wallet.payer]
);
```

The types you can find in the target folder after you built the program in the types folder

Comment: omfg it was the global:function_name, that was the solution

program was developed in anchor